# What is the better choice for Jackson performance and thread safety?

Tags: java, multithreading, json, jackson

What is the better way to use a Jackson serialized in multithreaded system:

- To create a new serializer object per each request, or
- To create a serializer factory as a bean and make all requests to use it centrally

Does it have a synchronized blocks in serialization/desalination process, that can impact on runtime performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-570?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel. It depends on what version you are using.

Comment: I am using now Gson, but I have a performance issues with it. I want to try the jackson.So I'll use the latest version.

Comment: According to your link I probably have to use the first approach. In this case, what will be an impact of creation on runtime performance?

Comment: Not much. The objects are cheap.

Comment: The link is broken